# length of array of mapped objects

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to convert the line below into python3 format, because it is python2 compatible only. The code below comes from: http://nadbordrozd.github.io/blog/2016/05/20/text-classification-with-word2vec/

```
self.dim = len(word2vec.itervalues().next())
```

After searching i found that the equivalent in python3 is

```
len(next(iter(word2vec.values())))
```

However when the class below is called it gives error: `len() of unsized object`
I seem to not be able to get the length of the array of mapped objects. What is the right way to convert the line above?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import collections

    class TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer(object):
        def __init__(self, word2vec):
            self.word2vec = word2vec
            self.word2weight = None
            self.dim = len(next(iter(word2vec.values())))
            #self.dim = len(word2vec.values())

        def fit(self, X, y):
            tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=lambda x: x)
            tfidf.fit(X)
            # if a word was never seen - it must be at least as infrequent
            # as any of the known words - so the default idf is the max of 
            # known idf's
            max_idf = max(tfidf.idf_)
            self.word2weight = collections.defaultdict(
                lambda: max_idf,
                [(w, tfidf.idf_[i]) for w, i in tfidf.vocabulary_.items()])

            return self

        def transform(self, X):
            return np.array([
                    np.mean([self.word2vec[w] * self.word2weight[w]
                             for w in words if w in self.word2vec] or
                            [np.zeros(self.dim)], axis=0)
                    for words in X
                ])
```

Comment: the `next` function doesn't return a sized object. This is because `next` gives ONE element and not the list of all elements in the iterator.

Comment: @TheophileDano so the initial implementation of the article is wrong?